# Is there a macOS ssh client that allows me to type fluid commands?

Tags: terminal, ssh

Terminal and iTerm uses whatever method they are using to ssh that basically slows down if the network connection to the server is slow. All the commands I type would show up on the screen seconds later. Is there a client I can use where the command would render faster on screen regardless the speed of the network?

P.S., with UDP being blocked, I cannot use mosh.

Answer (score 2):

As you cannot use mosh, your choices are very limited.

You can use the following perl-based wrapper for the standard OpenSSH command supplied with macOS to enable line-mode:

https://github.com/mnalis/ssh-line-mode/blob/master/sshlm

Remember to read the instructions before use:

https://github.com/mnalis/ssh-line-mode/blob/master/USAGE.txt

Comment: Okay let me give it a shot.

Comment: This should be on Homebrew, but [it's not](https://github.com/mnalis/ssh-line-mode/issues/2).